# Android Studio API response

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I basically have everything functioning following this tutorial on how to implement a API in flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data. I followed the tutorial but i get an error message "Failed to load Album". My understanding of this is that the server didn't respond with a 200 ok repsonse, but im not sure. I don't know how what the problem is and how i can get it to display the information. The API im using is a car registry, where you can type in a numberplate and get all the details for a vehicle.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('http://api.nrpla.de/Cz33849?api_token=JjCYzJA0B5FQPPjlWeyUqN3KSuaErwMyrryuQCmX7R6epHagtINaMjxfwaTGGyrl'),
      headers: {
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}



class Album {
  final String registration;
  final String type;
  final String brand;
  final String model;
  final String version;
  final String fuel_type;
  final String registration_status;
  final int engine_power;
  final String doors;
  final String leasing_period_start;
  final String leasing_period_end;
  final String color;
  final String body_type;

  Album({
    required this.registration,
    required this.type,
    required this.brand,
    required this.model,
    required this.version,
    required this.fuel_type,
    required this.registration_status,
    required this.engine_power,
    required this.doors,
    required this.leasing_period_start,
    required this.leasing_period_end,
    required this.color,
    required this.body_type,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      registration: json['registration'],
      type: json['type'],
      brand: json['brand'],
      model: json['model'],
      version: json['version'],
      fuel_type: json['fuel_type'],
      registration_status: json['registration_status'],
      engine_power: json['engine_power'],
      doors: json['doors'],
      leasing_period_start: json['leasing_period_start'],
      leasing_period_end: json['leasing_period_end'],
      color: json['color'],
      body_type: json['body_type'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.registration);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you check the result with `debugPrint(response)`?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: add the line after getting the response:
`final response = ...;
debugPrint(response);`

Answer (score 0):

You have consumed your `monthly limit` that's why you are not getting `data` from the API status code is 429

[image]